# Parsing XML SOAP response in PHP

Tags: php, xml, soap

I have been trying to parse an XML SOAP response in PHP but I continue to get errors. I cannot figure out why these errors are occuring.

Response from the server, stored in `$response` as a string (with sensitive data removed):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <s:Header>
        <h:ServerVersionInfo MajorVersion="15" MinorVersion="20" MajorBuildNumber="323" MinorBuildNumber="19" Version="V2017_10_09" xmlns:h="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
    </s:Header>
    <s:Body>
        <m:GetAttachmentResponse xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:t="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types">
            <m:ResponseMessages>
                <m:GetAttachmentResponseMessage ResponseClass="Success">
                    <m:ResponseCode>NoError</m:ResponseCode>
                    <m:Attachments>
                        <t:FileAttachment>
                            <t:AttachmentId Id="id number"/>
                            <t:Name>message-footer.txt</t:Name>
                            <t:ContentType>text/plain</t:ContentType>
                            <t:ContentId>contentid.prod.outlook.com</t:ContentId>
                            <t:Content>file contents</t:Content>
                        </t:FileAttachment>
                    </m:Attachments>
                </m:GetAttachmentResponseMessage>
            </m:ResponseMessages>
        </m:GetAttachmentResponse>
    </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

My code:

```
$data = simplexml_load_string($response);
$fileData = $data
    ->children('s:', true)->Body
    ->children('m:', true)->GetAttachmentResponse->ResponseMessages->GetAttachmentResponseMessage->Attachments
    ->children('t:', true)->FileAttachment;
```

I need to be able to get the file name, content type, and content. I continue to get the following error: `Node no longer exists` (on line 4 here).

For reference, I have been following this guide: https://joshtronic.com/2014/07/13/parsing-soap-responses-with-simplexml/

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know how to read such a complex XML file with `simplexml`, but I know that `DOMDocument` works very well for it.

```
<?php

$source = file_get_contents('file.xml');

$dom = new DOMDocument("1.0", "UTF-8");
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$dom->loadXml($source);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$xpath->registerNamespace("s", "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/");
$xpath->registerNamespace("m", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages");
$xpath->registerNamespace("xsd", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema");
$xpath->registerNamespace("xsi", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance");
$xpath->registerNamespace("t", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types");

$fileAttachments = $xpath->query('//m:GetAttachmentResponseMessage/m:Attachments/t:FileAttachment');

/* @var DOMElement $fileAttachment */
foreach ($fileAttachments as $fileAttachment) {
    echo 'Name: ' . $xpath->query('t:Name', $fileAttachment)->item(0)->nodeValue . "\n";
    echo 'ContentType: ' . $xpath->query('t:ContentType', $fileAttachment)->item(0)->nodeValue  . "\n";
    echo 'Content: ' . $xpath->query('t:Content', $fileAttachment)->item(0)->nodeValue  . "\n";
}
```